# Faulty [fault]​

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I think that the [fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fault) needs to be burninated. It appears that this tag is used to show [segmentation-fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/segmentation-fault)s and other problems. Several questions tagged with this tag hasn't got any attention because these questions aren't tagged with a language tag. Moreover, nobody can be an expert in [fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fault)s. It is a tag which is too broad as faults are of different types.

So, are we ready for burnination?

Comment: Why can't I remove "Burninate" from the title? An error pops up:"Title contains a [tag] prefix; please use the tag field to enter tags instead." How do I use a "tag field"?

Comment: Psst.. You can put a [Unicode zero width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) at the start of the title, and then the system will let you post it. The "tag field" is the "Tags" box above the "Post Your Question" button

Comment: How do I copy paste that character? Could you change the title to "Faulty [fault]" or "[fault] is faulty" or something like that? BTW, Thanks for telling me what is the "tag field".

Comment: On my linux system, there is a "Character map" where you can find it, and windows has something like that too. I don't have enough rep to edit on meta though.

Comment: Thanks. I copy-pasted it from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)

Comment: Yes; it is too general and should be burninated, retagging questions when appropriate (and all the other usual cleanups).  What's the volume of questions…oh, 292 of them.  Grrr…doable manually, but a lot of grunt work.  It is a good idea to give an indication of the scope of a problem in a burninate request.